# how do i link from an ibook to another?

Tags: ipad, hyperlink, ibooks

I'm making an catalog for a client with al his products. Each product has his own pdf-file. Now i want to link from the main catalog to another pdf-file in my ibook.

These files are already in ibook, it's necessary to link without an internet connection. Does anyone now how i can link to this file? Or does anyone know the path to reach this document?

I'm looking forward to any of your answers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible.